# Ansible - templates with items won't works

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04

I run this in a ansible playbook for copy files from the directory "templates" of the ansible role and I get error...

```
- name:  "Copy templates"
templates: src={{item.src}} dest={{item.dest}}
with_items:
    - { src: 'tpl1', dest: '/etc/tpl1' }
    - { src: 'tpl2', dest: '/etc/tpl2' }
    - { src: 'tpl3', dest: '/etc/tpl3' }
```

Error Output:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'templates'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/myuser/Desktop/mydir/roles/rolename/tasks/main.yml': line 73, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name:  "Copy templates"
^ here
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The module is named [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html), not `templates`.

```yaml
- name: "Copy templates"
  template:
    src="{{item.src}}"
    dest="{{item.dest}}"
```